# Error starting nodeos

Tags: nodeos

I have completed the following steps so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos --recursive
cd eos
./eosio_build.sh -s "EOS"
cd build
sudo make install

Created genesis.json form repo

~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/genesis.json

Ran nodeos once to generate the ocnfig.ini

Added p2p nodes from privex in config.ini

Added plugins to config.ini

plugin = eosio::producer_plugin 
plugin = eosio::wallet_api_plugin 
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin 
plugin = eosio::http_plugin 
plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin
```

I get the following error when running nodeos

```
nodeos --genesis-json genesis.json
1084492ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:208          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin
1084492ms thread-0   main.cpp:113                  main                 ] 10 assert_exception: Assert Exception
!fc::exists( my->blocks_dir / "blocks.log" ): Genesis state can only be set on a fresh blockchain.
    {}
    thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:362 plugin_initialize
```

After this I tried to run it without the genesis option:

```
sudo nodeos
1138743ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:208          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin
1138752ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:123             open                 ] Log is nonempty
1138753ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:141             open                 ] Index is nonempty
1138781ms thread-0   wallet_plugin.cpp:39          plugin_initialize    ] initializing wallet plugin
1138782ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:290           plugin_initialize    ] configured http to listen on 127.0.0.1:8080
1138782ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2947           plugin_initialize    ] Initialize net plugin
1138783ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2971           plugin_initialize    ] host: 0.0.0.0 port: 9876 
1138783ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:3043           plugin_initialize    ] my node_id is 38b1bd1bd30839851ea25cd3e7a9487b942d10c97c314988f332070da323346a
1138784ms thread-0   main.cpp:104                  main                 ] nodeos version c9b7a247
1138784ms thread-0   main.cpp:105                  main                 ] eosio root is /home/arthur/.local/share
1138804ms thread-0   main.cpp:113                  main                 ] 10 assert_exception: Assert Exception
db.revision() >= head->block_num: fork database is inconsistent with shared memory
    {"db":0,"head":1}
    thread-0  controller.cpp:243 init

    {}
    thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:454 plugin_startup
```

**Update**

I followed the suggestions below, but I am getting a lot of connection closes

```
2353391ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:1969           connect              ] host: peering.dutcheos.io port: 9876 
2353679ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2189           operator()           ] Peer eu-west-nl.eosamsterdam.net:9876 closed connection
2353680ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2189           operator()           ] Peer eu1.eosdac.io:49876 closed connection
2354049ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2189           operator()           ] Peer p2p.eosio.cr:5418 closed connection
2354049ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2189           operator()           ] Peer p2p.eosio.cr:1976 closed connection
2354049ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2189           operator()           ] Peer node1.eosnewyork.io:6987 closed connection
2354055ms thread-0   producer_plugin.cpp:290       on_incoming_block    ] Received block 9c3f8adaefe5c21f... #7000 @ 2018-06-09T12:56:41.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 6999, conf: 0, latency: 690153055 ms]
2354122ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2189           operator()           ] Peer pub1.eosys.io:6637 closed connection
2356112ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:1983           operator()           ] Unable to resolve mainnet.eosoasis.io:9876: Host not found (authoritative)
```

Comment: did you run this node once before? because if the answer is yes, for the second time you don't need the genesis anymore and you will be getting this error. just run without genesis.json

Comment: Yes i did run it once to generate the ini file. however I get another error. Updated question

Answer (score 2):

Fully ready solutions

```
cd
wget https://eosnodes.privex.io/static/genesis.json
nodeos --genesis-json genesis.json
nano ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
```

add to config

```
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_api_plugin
```

https://eosnodes.privex.io/?config=1

```
rm ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data/blocks/* -r
rm ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data/state/* -r
nodeos --genesis-json genesis.json
```

Everything works

Answer (score 0):

I myself am a beginner, try this method.

First run should be with --delete-all-blocks and --genesis-json

```
--delete-all-blocks --genesis-json genesis.json
```

you can clean the block and state file using below command

```
rm ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data/blocks/* -r
rm ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data/state/* -r
```

https://steemit.com/eos/@fundurian/learning-diary-connecting-to-eos-mainnet

Comment: Thanks I managed to get much further but I am getting a lot of connection closes in the nodeos log, updated question